# is spoofing CA to sign application possible?

Tags: malware, certificate-authority, spoofing

Is it possible to spoof the CA of any server to sign some application?
As like as what [CarbonCopy](https://github.com/paranoidninja/Pandoras-Box/blob/master/python/CarbonCopy.py) claims?

Comment: Welcome! Links may become broken so its best to include the details of `CarbonCopy` in your question. Also, to what degree of spoofing are you referring to? Private keys cannot be spoofed which is why we're at a threat level of Green.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CarbonCopy  creates a self-signed certificates which looks like the original certificate, i.e. subject, issuer etc seem to match. But, the certificate is not signed by the specified issuer at all. This means if a proper validation of the certificate is done no local trust anchor will be found and the certificate will be rejected as untrusted.

Comment: Thank you, But what about signing executables,CarbonCopy can to evading AVs properly?

Comment: @linux: This depends on the AV. According to [this recent (2017) paper](http://users.umiacs.umd.edu/~tdumitra/papers/CCS-2017.pdf) some AV are so gullible that they consider a binary harmless if it has some signature on the first place, even if the signature does not match the binary at all. Such AV might probably also fall for tricks with invalid certificates although this was not tested in the paper. If instead a proper signature validation is done against with only trustable CA as root then this kind of signature will be detected as untrusted.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible. Certificates are a chained tree, where each certificate is chained to another via digital signature. chain ends with a root certificate which is presented in a self-signed form and must be explicitly trusted by a client.

When you spoof certificate, it will have different signature created by a non-legitimate public key. When you attempt to bind spoofed certificate to legitimate chain, parent CA certificate will fail spoofed certificate signature validation. That is, in order to correctly spoof CA certificate, you must either, steal or reconstruct key pair. Both options are quite hard tasks.

Answer (score 1):

In theory, if everything is done properly, it should not be possible to fake a signature.  In reality though, there has been cases where the digital signatures in the wild have been faked (or potentially "fakeable") due to cryptanalysis or hacking.  There is a recent paper about how the use of poor public-keypair generation in various servers and devices have led to the creation of weak keys which in turn can potentially be broken and fake signatures generated. 
Here is a very good paper on the subject:  https://factorable.net/weakkeys12.extended.pdf

Other ways could be to make up ones own keys and sign it, and somehow attack the target system by installing another root certificate that would verify your fake signature.  There are actually limited legitimate reasons why one would create a private CA and store it's certs as root certs on computers you manage (for example, in a corporate intranet where one needs to monitor outgoing SSL communications)..but when done out in the wild with malicious intent, it is a very powerful attack that cause a lot of trouble, but it is unethical and should never be done.

Always generate keys securely and protect them, and don't hack PKI!